# Python iterate through list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have the below list of dictionaries -

```
results = [
     {'type': 'check_datatype',
      'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': ['car_id','index'], 'd_type': 'str'},
      'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
      'Result': False},
    {'type': 'check_string_consistency',
      'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': ['car_id'], 'string_length': 6},
      'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
      'Result': False}
    ]
```

I want output list with below output where key and value fields are coming from kwargs key in the above list -

id|key|value|index

[[1,table,cars,null],[1,columns,car_id,1],[1,columns,index,2]
[1,dtype,str,null],[2,table,cars,null],[2,columns,car_id,null],[2,string_length,6,null]]

Update - Now, i want one more column in output - uniquehaschode --> here unique hashcode means Dictionaries with the same keys and values should generate the same id or hash. Hence if key value pairs are same in dictionary 'kwargs', then they should return the same hashcode. Output should be like this -

[[1,table,cars,null,uniquehaschode1],[1,columns,car_id,1,uniquehaschode1],[1,columns,index,2,uniquehaschode1]
[1,dtype,str,null,uniquehaschode1],[2,table,cars,null,uniquehaschode2],[2,columns,car_id,null,uniquehaschode2],[2,string_length,6,null,uniquehaschode2]]

Also, i don't want to insert anything into this table if a particular uniquehaschode already exists.

Update2: I want to create a dataframe with below schema. args_id will be same for each unique pair of (kwargs and check_name). i want to run the above list of dictionaries everyday and hence for different date run, args_id should be same if
unique pair of (kwargs and check_name) has come again. i want to store this result into a dataframe everyday and then put it into my delta table of spark.

```
Type|time|args_id
check_datatype|2021-03-29|0
check_string_consistency|2021-03-29|1
check_datatype|2021-03-30|0
```

Until now, i was using below code -

```
type_results = [[elt['type'] for
                   elt in results]
        checkColumns = ['type']
        spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
        DF = spark.createDataFrame(data=results, schema=checkColumns)
        DF = DF.withColumn("time", F.current_timestamp())
       DF = DF.withColumn("args_id", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need:

```
results = [
     {'type': 'check_datatype',
      'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': ['car_id','index'], 'd_type': 'str'},
      'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
      'Result': False},
    {'type': 'check_string_consistency',
      'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': ['car_id'], 'string_length': 6},
      'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
      'Result': False}
    ]

result_list = []
for c, l in enumerate(results, start=1):
    for key, value in l['kwargs'].items():
        if isinstance(value,list):
            if len(value) == 1:
                result_list.append([str(c),key,value[0],'null'])
                continue
            for i in value:
                result_list.append([str(c),key,i,str(value.index(i)+1)])
        else:
            result_list.append([str(c),key,value,'null'])

print(result_list)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'table', 'cars', 'null'], ['1', 'columns', 'car_id', '1'], ['1', 'columns', 'index', '2'], ['1', 'd_type', 'str', 'null'], ['2', 'table', 'cars', 'null'], ['2', 'columns', 'car_id', 'null'], ['2', 'string_length', 6, 'null']]
```

As for the Update part you can use `pip install maps`:

```
import maps
results = [
     {'type': 'check_datatype',
      'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': ['car_id','index'], 'd_type': 'str'},
      'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
      'Result': False},
    {'type': 'check_string_consistency',
      'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': ['car_id'], 'string_length': 6},
      'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
      'Result': False},
    {'type': 'check_string_consistency',
     'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': ['car_id'], 'string_length': 6},
     'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
     'Result': False}
    ]
 
result_list = []
for c, l in enumerate(results, start=1):
    h = hash(maps.FrozenMap.recurse(l['kwargs']))
    for key, value in l['kwargs'].items():
        if isinstance(value,list):
            if len(value) == 1:
                result_list.append([str(c),key,value[0],'null', f'{h}-{c}'])
                continue
            for i in value:
                result_list.append([str(c),key,i,str(value.index(i)+1),f'{h}-{c}'])
        else:
            result_list.append([str(c),key,value,'null',f'{h}-{c}'])

print(result_list)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'table', 'cars', 'null', '-6654319495930648246-1'], ['1', 'columns', 'car_id', '1', '-6654319495930648246-1'], ['1', 'columns', 'index', '2', '-6654319495930648246-1'], ['1', 'd_type', 'str', 'null', '-6654319495930648246-1'], ['2', 'table', 'cars', 'null', '-3876605863049152209-2'], ['2', 'columns', 'car_id', 'null', '-3876605863049152209-2'], ['2', 'string_length', 6, 'null', '-3876605863049152209-2'], ['3', 'table', 'cars', 'null', '-3876605863049152209-3'], ['3', 'columns', 'car_id', 'null', '-3876605863049152209-3'], ['3', 'string_length', 6, 'null', '-3876605863049152209-3']]
```

Comment: Hi David, I have just edited the output in the last column index which should be null if we don't have multiple values for a key and it should have indexing starting from 1 if there are multiple values. Just see the output, I have edited it.

Comment: HI David, the output is a print statement, i actually want it to be in list of lists format like [[1,table,cars,null],[1,columns,car_id,1]........ [2,'string_length',6,null]]

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer.
You can also replace 'null' with None.

Comment: thanks david. I am not sure why but when i am trying to store this list in a dataframe, i am getting below error - TypeError: field value: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'>                    checkColumns = ['args_id', 'key', 'value','list_index']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=result_list, schema=checkColumns)

Comment: Not sure probably the int,
Maybe try converting all to str.
Edited.

Comment: Hi David, can you give me a new column in this list which gives a unique hashcode for each unique key value pairs in kwargs key?

Comment: @SumitDwivedi can you elaborate?
Or open a new thread.

Comment: I have updated the question now.please check. Now only i need 2 columns

Comment: Hi David, i am sorry but there is a mistake i did last time. I have updated the output once again.

Comment: Updated. used ```uniquehaschode-<index>``` 

just for it to be clear what is the hash and index.

Comment: thanks david. you are genius. I have one more requirement related to this ask.

Comment: Hi David, could you please help me with the updated output?

Comment: Hi David, code is not working in case if the hashcode already exists.

Comment: Hi David, why you have used hash function and not hashlib?

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [
     {'type': 'check_datatype',
      'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': ['car_id','index'], 'd_type': 'str'},
      'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
      'Result': False},
    {'type': 'check_string_consistency',
      'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': ['car_id'], 'string_length': 6},
      'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
      'Result': False}
    ]

for each in results:
    print(each['kwargs'])
```

Comment: thats wrong. expected output should give each key value pair in kwargs as a new row and id should be same for all these rows which belong to same dictionary. You can check my expected output in question. What you have done is very simple